# Ajax username check keeps returning true (code posted)

Tags: php, ajax

Below I posted the code! Anything will help! I got this from a website because I couldn't figure it out. It works and displays under the username input but it will always say the username is available. I even created a user 'bob' and when I entered the username 'bob', it said it was available.

## Ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var timeout = null;
        var subdomainOK = true;
        $(function () {



            $("form").submit(function () {

                if (!subdomainOK) { return false; }
                if (!$('#TermsCB').is(':checked')) {
                    $('#TermsValidation').html("You need to accept the terms and conditions");
                    return false;
                }

                if ($(this).valid()) {
                    $('[type=submit]').button('loading');
                }
                return true;
            });

        });

      function check_availability(){  

    //get the username  
    var username = $('#Subdomain').val();  

    //use ajax to run the check  
    $.post("inc/accountcheck.php", { username: username },  
        function(result){  
            //if the result is 1  
            if(result = 0){  
                //show that the username is available  
                $('#SubdomainValidation').html(username + ' is Taken');  
            }else{  
                //show that the username is NOT available  
                $('#SubdomainValidation').html(username + ' is Available');  
            }  
    });  

  }  
 </script>
```

## Php

```
 <?php
//connect to database  
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'seadude246');  
mysql_select_db('socialdb');  

//get the username  
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Subdomain']);  

//mysql query to select field username if it's equal to the username that we check '  
$result = mysql_query('select username from users where username = "'. $username .'"');  

//if number of rows fields is bigger them 0 that means it's NOT available '  
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){  
    //and we send 0 to the ajax request  
    echo 0;  
}else{  
    //else if it's not bigger then 0, then it's available '  
    //and we send 1 to the ajax request  
    echo 1;  
}
?>
```

Comment: Adding as a comment rather than an answer - somewhat deliriously tired right now, not trusting myself - is that a `if (result = 0)` supposed to be an `if (result == 0)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your php code, the key you passed to the `$_POST['']` array should be username, not Subdomain because from your javascript, the key you send via ajax is username and the id of the username field is Subdomain

So you should instead have

`$_POST['username']`

Comment: you missed something